# Does azure's simulator use real connection from config for service bus?

Tags: azure, remote-server, azureservicebus, azure-compute-emulator

When I use service bus locally with azure simulator it requires real connection in config like this

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="StorageConnection"
            connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=***;AccountKey=***" />

    <add name="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"
            connectionString="Endpoint=***;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=***" />

</connectionStrings>
```

Sometimes when I run it locally it seems that service bus tasks that I handle came from real connection described in config. But I'm not sure about this. And it is arbitrarily I cann't check it properly. So when service bus is started locally does it use real connection or not? If not why it requires  for starting service bus with azure simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure emulator does not include a Service Bus emulator, only a Compute emulator (web/worker roles) and a Storage emulator (blob/table/queue).

You'll either need to use the Azure Service Bus directly or install Service Bus locally (you can install to Windows 7 sp1 and Windows 8 for dev purposes). Information about Service Bus for Windows Server is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn282144.aspx).